# Looking to find inventor certificate

Tags: inventor, invention

Is there a way to find and get an inventor certificate and verify the inventor's identity online?

Comment: I’m involved with patents professionally and have never heard this term. What do you mean by an inventor’s certificate? The official ribboned paper copy of the patent?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I read about them few months ago, was not familiar with it either. It was kind of a patent in Socialist countries. [Presentation about them by the EPO](https://documents.epo.org/projects/babylon/eponot.nsf/0/9150186096F3FE21C125861F002907E7/$File/EPOPIC_2020_Eva_Strakova_Juergen%20Muehl.pdf). Perhaps OP can check it out, I am unsure if it might address his question.

Comment: Online identity verification is going to be a thorny issue regardless of what an "inventor certificate" is. I think the OP would do well to explain why they need proof of identity.